# iPhone app installs on iPhone from Xcode but crashes

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-provisioning, xcode

I added my device (iPhone) through the provisioning profile, created the right provisioning profile and did everything the Apple dev guide said to do, but when I try to test my app on my iPhone it installs, but once it runs, it doesn't get past the splash screen before it crashes. It runs perfectly on the simulator and has no errors or warnings.

Error log:
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x2fe0124a dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*) + 446
1   dyld                            0x2fe01058 _dyld_start + 48

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000009      r2: 0x00000009      r3: 0x000b5000
    r4: 0x000b501c    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x00000005      r7: 0x2feb3a80
    r8: 0x2feda18c    r9: 0x2ff01964     r10: 0x2feb44f4     r11: 0x000b4000
    ip: 0x2ff01984    sp: 0x2feb3a38      lr: 0x2feb3a14      pc: 0x2feb524a
  cpsr: 0x60000030

Comment: does your application run through the testing profile?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? What iPhone are you using? iPhone 4? iPhone 3Gs? What is your "architectures setting" in "build settings"?

Comment: @xuzhe

Architectures is armv6 and armv7, iphone 3gs and xcode 3.2.6

Comment: What do you mean by the testing profile? It runs in the simulator

Comment: What version of iOS is your iPhone 3GS running?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure from the stacktrace. But are you using distribution profile? If yes then try using debug provisioning profile.